# How to extract text using regular expressions with optional patterns present?

Tags: regex, r, string, match

I would like to extract the text between *"one: "* and *"two: "* and between *"two: "* and *"three: "* in the string **s1** *"one: bla 1 two: bla2 three: bla3"*. However *"two: bla2 "* is not necessarily present in the string **s2**. So if it is **s2** *"one: bla 1 three: bla3"* it should also work.

I've come up with the following R-Code, but my attempt with the additional parentheses around the *"two:..."* and the question mark doesn't work:

```
library(gsubfn)
s1 <- "one: bla 1 two: bla2 three: bla3"
s2 <- "one: bla 1 three: bla3"
strapplyc(s1, "one: (.*) (two: (.*))? three: (.*)")
strapplyc(s2, "one: (.*) (two: (.*))? three: (.*)")
```

Comment: What about just splitting on `\w*(one|two|three):\w*`?

Comment: If two is not present then your regular expression requires that there be two spaces before three but there is only one space before three in s2 so try putting the second space within the parens so that ? acts on it too: `strapplyc(s2, "one: (.*) (two: (.*) )?three: (bla3)")`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck your suggestion seems to work for s2, but not for s1.

Comment: @StevenDoggart It returns the one/two/three, but I couldn't get it to return everything in between, yet. I think I need sth. like "(.*) (one|two|three): (.*)"

Comment: I meant that you should split on matches rather than find matches.  In other words, use something like `strsplit`.

Comment: OK, got it: something like strsplit(s1, split="(one: |two: |three: )")

Comment: OK.  Also replace .* with [^:]* to prevent it from consuming colons.  `strapplyc(s1, "one: ([^:]*) (two: ([^;]*) )?three: (bla3)")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is that the `.*` after the `one:` is also consuming the `two:` part and the text after it. So for example the the matching groups in your line would be

```
1: "bla 1 two: bla2"
2: [empty]
3: "bla3"
```

You could fix this by making the first asterisk non-greedy with a question mark.

Some other points: I think you should put the space inside the parentheses in the `two:` part, otherwise when it is not available there will have to be two spaces between the `one:` and `two:` part.

Additionally, for a minor tidy up, you could make the parentheses around the optional part non-capturing with with `?:`. You only want to capture three things, and the parentheses around the `two:` part are just for the precedence, so it's not necessary to capture.

So altogether you would have something like this:

```
strapplyc(s1, "one: (.*?)(?: two: (.*))? three: (bla3)")
```